# Java cache objects to disk

Tags: java, caching, serialization

I have a collection of rather large objects (one complex class, can be made serializable) and an algorithm operating on it. The algorithm has to work on each object several times, and only needs a few objects of the collection at once.

To save RAM, I'd like to cache objects that weren't used for a while by the algorithm to disk if there isn't enough memory anymore. The algorithm needs to know which objects are on disk so it can avoid them as long as possible.

How do I achieve this? Do I have to implement this on my own or are there existing libraries?

**Edit:**

I probably won't have more than a few hundred of those objects since I discard them as soon as possible. Each object (simplified description) contains a 2D-array with up to 256x256 elements. Consider an average load of the main Array around about 30% and the child array being nearly full most of the time. Each object in the array contains some smaller data: A few array lists with vectors in it, a properties HashMap and so on. I outsourced most of the data with instancing so that it is fairly small.

Comment: Before even going into this, how many objects are we talking about? What does their class look like?

Comment: Apache commons have a cache lib: http://commons.apache.org/dormant/cache/

Comment: you can refer here http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/configuration/fast-restart.html

Comment: Most caching APIs, including ehcache, support a "least recently used" cache ejection strategy. This would support what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why do you believe that it will save RAM? Your expectations are close to how OS works. It stores memory pages on the disk and uses RAM for performance optimization.

Comment: +Karol I have absolutely no idea how an OS handles memory. Why shouldn't storing objects on disk save ram?

Comment: instead of caching them put them in a large queue and let a background task finish them in series. just make sure they finish faster than they are invoked !!

Comment: +AntJavaDev I already tried queuing them, but because most of the times several of those objects are needed to be processed together by the algorithm, it doesn't work. In my most efficient implementation object counts still increases linearly.

Comment: I did not say that it should not save RAM but there are cases that will not save. What if your objects are already on the disk? Why do you care about RAM? Have you recognized that OS Memory Management is not sufficient for you? My point is that your objective is to save the RAM and you are describing a solution that may be wrong. You should explain what do you base on or remove misleading part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to a nice guy on GitHub who mentioned MapDB, which fits the use-case pretty well. It has memory/count and time based item eviction. The documentation even [has an example](https://jankotek.gitbooks.io/mapdb/content/htreemap/) (section "Expiration Overflow"):

```
DB dbDisk = DBMaker
        .fileDB(file)
        .make();

DB dbMemory = DBMaker
        .memoryDB()
        .make();

// Big map populated with data expired from cache
HTreeMap onDisk = dbDisk
        .hashMap("onDisk")
        .create();

// fast in-memory collection with limited size
HTreeMap inMemory = dbMemory
        .hashMap("inMemory")
        .expireAfterGet(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        //this registers overflow to `onDisk`
        .expireOverflow(onDisk)
        //good idea is to enable background expiration
        .expireExecutor(Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2))
        .create();
```